# Is it possible to modify the order of the item types in items.xml?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I was asked recently whether we can try to modify the order of items in the items.xml file.Since the order is determined by the XSD file, is it possible to write your own XSD file and change this logic?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @JohannesNolte,it is not about the exact requirement.It is about whether it is possible and if so how?

Comment: I was just curious since there are (limited) ways to structure your items.xml files like extensions or typegroups. But I also asked myself the same question since the hybris way does not appear to be very clean.

Answer (score 0):

Xsd determines the order and hierarchy of tags inside an xml. It depends on which items you want to modify the order for.
For instance, if you want to modify the order of individual `itemtype` tags inside a `typegroup` tag, or you want to modify the order of individual `typegroup` tags inside a `itemtypes` tag, you can do it without modifying xsd, because your xml will still be valid against the xml.
Could you be more specific about your needs? What elements you want to modify the order for? and for what reasons?

Comment: I'm think it's about the order of the tags enumtypes, maptypes, itemtypes, relations and so on. If you mess with those, your xml will be invalid. It would be much more reasonable to group those by feature rather than by type.

Comment: How does this check get enforced in Hybris?